# Sample dialog definition for customizing 'Save As' common dialog box

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

I'm trying to customize standard win32 "Save As" dialog box. My code looks like this:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;
//... skipped
ofn.Flags = OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE;
ofn.lpTemplateName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(RES); // what is the RES?
//... skipped
GetSaveFileName(&ofn);
```

But I can't find any single example of what is the RES. It must be resource file or something like this. I need a simple example to start with. All I need at the moment is to add text line to the bottom of standard 'Save As' dialog box.

Comment: No, this is not how you do this anymore. That's the mechanism for XP. Now you use `IFileDialogCustomize`.

Comment: Ok, but I still need to support XP.

Comment: Then you need to use `GetSaveFileName` on XP, with a template resource, and `IFileDialog` and `IFileDialogCustomize` on Vista and later.

Comment: This is the issue - I can't write template resource because I don't know how and I can't find any example of template resource where standard 'Save As' dialog box is extended.

Comment: There are a gazillion such examples online. Surely a websearch will reveal one.

Comment: Ok I will try again. I don't know why I didn't find any after hours of searching.

Comment: [Open and Save As Dialog Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960.aspx) contains exhaustive documentation on [Customizing Common Dialog Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646951.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the sample:
[CommDlgCust.zip](http://files.rsdn.ru/10117/CommDlgCust.zip)

It is 14 years old but still works. Old project file can be easily opened with Visual C++ 2013.

So the "RES" thing is a dialog definition located in rc file. The answer I wanted is this:

```
IDD_OPENSAVE DIALOG FIXED IMPURE  0, 0, 280, 53
STYLE WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_STATIC,"Static",SS_ETCHEDFRAME,6,6,266,38
    CTEXT           "",IDC_STATIC_HINT,12,10,256,28,SS_CENTERIMAGE
END
```

Here is code sample based on the CommDlgCust.zip:

```
// ---------- resource.h
// last line of the file must be an empty line!

#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC              -1
#endif

#define IDC_STATIC_HINT                 1001
#define IDD_OPENSAVE                    110

// ---------- project.rc

#include "resource.h"

#include "targetver.h"
#include "windows.h"

IDD_OPENSAVE DIALOG FIXED IMPURE  0, 0, 280, 53
STYLE WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_STATIC,"Static",SS_ETCHEDFRAME,6,6,266,38
    CTEXT           "",IDC_STATIC_HINT,12,10,256,28,SS_CENTERIMAGE
END

// ---------- main.cpp

// ...skipped...

UINT CALLBACK OfnHookProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, UINT /*wParam*/, LONG lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        OFNOTIFY* pofNotify = (OFNOTIFY*)lParam;
        switch (pofNotify->hdr.code)
        {
            case CDN_FOLDERCHANGE:
            {
                LPTSTR pszPathName;
                pszPathName = new TCHAR[_MAX_DIR];
                HWND hTrueDlg = GetParent(hDlg);
                SendMessage(hTrueDlg, CDM_GETFOLDERPATH, _MAX_PATH, (LONG)pszPathName);
                SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_HINT, pszPathName);
                delete[] pszPathName;
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

bool MyGetSaveFileName()
{
    WCHAR lpstrFile[1024] = {0};

    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    memset(&ofn, 0, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    ofn.hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(ofn.hwndOwner, GWL_HINSTANCE);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = L"*.TXT";
    ofn.lpstrFile = lpstrFile;
    ofn.nMaxFile = 1023;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = L"Save";
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE | OFN_ENABLEHOOK;
    ofn.lpTemplateName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_OPENSAVE);
    ofn.lpfnHook = OfnHookProc;

    if (GetSaveFileName(&ofn) != 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I hope this will help someone.