# How do I replace the default right click context menu in a file open dialog box with my own

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, modal-dialog

I would like to create a custom File Open dialog where I can replace the default context menu options shown when the user right clicks one of the files in the list, with my own context menu.

Based on articles such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900100/sample-dialog-definition-for-customizing-save-as-common-dialog-box) one, and [this](http://www.equestionanswers.com/vcpp/file-open-dialog.php) one, I tried adding:

```
UINT CALLBACK OfnHookProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, UINT wParam, LONG lParam)
```

and then refer to it using

```
ofn.lpfnHook = OfnHookProc;
```

I guess the ideal solution will be a class derived from **[OPENFILENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea)**. Not sure how.

Comment: There is no way to do this with a standard dialog, and certainly not with an OFN hook. You would have to manually subclass the embedded Shell window directly and intercept mouse clicks before they reach it. Otherwise, just make your own custom dialog from scratch, then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I thought using a similar method to http://www.equestionanswers.com/vcpp/file-open-dialog.php

Comment: You already linked to that article in your question. And there is nothing in either article you linked to that even comes close to touching on what you are trying to accomplish with the context menu.

Comment: I agree entirely.

Answer (score 1):

> For the [Explorer-style Open dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/customizing-common-dialog-boxes?redirectedfrom=MSDN) box:
>
> - The default templates are **not available for modification**.
> - The hook procedure **does not receive messages** intended for the standard controls in the dialog box.

So there seems little possibility to *replace the default context menu* via editing or subclassing the open dialog itself.

> From the user's perspective, the chief benefit of the common dialog
> box is its **consistent** appearance and functionality from
> application to application. **Hiding** original controls or otherwise
> **changing** the intended functionality of the original controls is a **less appropriate** customization.

However, there is a workaround maybe help:

Add your context menu item to the default one as an addition. Like this:

[image]

Refer to "[Creating Cascading Menus with the ExtendedSubCommandsKey Registry Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers#creating-cascading-menus-with-the-extendedsubcommandskey-registry-entry)" for more detailed information.

**Note:** Modifying registry will affect all application instead of only your own application. So make sure keep this modification in a mini, required scope. For example, if putting this change in **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`** is enough don't put it in **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`**.

Comment: Do I need to restart explorer.exe after such change?

Comment: You can avoid restarting using `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, 0, NULL, NULL);` to notify the shell to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @remy-lebeau, you can do that using window subclassing as listed below:

1. get hWnd of the File Open dialog
2. replace WndProc via SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, ..)
3. after that you will be able to track mouse position and handle WM_RBUTTONDOWN

To get window handle, you can use FindWindowEx, EnumWindows or even SetWindowsHookEx. Don't forget to pass unhandled messages to the original window procedure.

Comment: Too good to be true.. Can you send me a code snippet?

Comment: I'm under NDA to be honest. My apologies. But what exactly is "too good"? This is just Windows API, there is nothing special here.